# Pegar uma Entry do TKinter e salvar em uma variável

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, programação-estruturada

Fiz essa janela inicial onde pega os dados, e quando o cliente a usa-se, após fornecer os dados e confirmar, fecha-se e mantive-se os dados salvos em uma variável que não estivesse presa a um aninhamento de DEF, ou seja, que pude-se usar a qualquer momento futuramente, mesmo estando fora da janela do TKinter.
Quando crio uma variável, dentro de DEF para obter as informações, não consigo usar fora do mesmo. Mas quando crio fora de DEF, ela não recebe a informação do Entry(Opção do TKinter). Estou usando o Python 3.6.

```css
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()

def __init__():
    pass
def ok():
    nick = str(CaixaDeEntrada1.get())
    patente = str(CaixaDeEntrada2.get())
    pagpromocao = str(CaixaDeEntrada3.get())
    CaixaDeEntrada3['bg'] = 'white'
    if nick in ' ':
        CaixaDeEntrada1['bg'] = 'pink'
        erro['text'] = 'Preencha todos os campos!'
    else:
        CaixaDeEntrada1['bg'] = 'white'
    if patente in ' ':
        CaixaDeEntrada2['bg'] = 'pink'
        erro['text'] = 'Preencha todos os campos!'
    else:
        CaixaDeEntrada2['bg'] = 'white'
    if pagpromocao in ' ':
        CaixaDeEntrada3['bg'] = 'pink'
        erro['text'] = 'Preencha todos os campos!'
    else:
        CaixaDeEntrada3['bg'] = 'white'
    if nick != '' and patente != '' and pagpromocao != '':
        janela.destroy()


#==========================================Janela Inicial:

titulo1 = Label(bg='#191970', font=('Arial', '14', 'bold'), fg='white', text='BEM VINDO ao RELATÓRIOS DIC')
titulo1.place(x='13', y='10')

CaixaDeEntrada1 = Entry(width=25, bg='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', '10'))
CaixaDeEntrada1.place(x=130, y=50)
Info1 = Label(font=('Arial', '11', 'bold'), fg='white', bg='#191970', text='Nick:')
Info1.place(x=10, y=50)

CaixaDeEntrada2 = Entry(width=25, bg='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', '10'))
CaixaDeEntrada2.place(x=130, y=75)
Info2 = Label(font=('Arial', '11', 'bold'), fg='white', bg='#191970', text='Patente:')
Info2.place(x=10, y=75)

CaixaDeEntrada3 = Entry(width=25, bg='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', '10'))
CaixaDeEntrada3.place(x=130, y=100)
Info3 = Label(font=('Arial', '11', 'bold'), fg='white', bg='#191970', text='Pág. Promoção:')
Info3.place(x=10, y=100)

erro = Label(bg='#191970', fg='red', font=('Arial', '11'), text='')
erro.place(x=135, y=125)

proximo = Button(width='39', text='Próximo', font=('Arial','10'), command=ok)
proximo.place(x=15, y=150)

#=======================================FimDaJanelaInicial

#Propriedades da janela:
janela.resizable(width=False, height=False)
janela.configure(bg='#191970')
janela.wm_iconbitmap('ICO.ico')
janela.title('Relatórios DIC - Por WellersonOP')
janela.geometry('350x190+450+300')
janela.mainloop()
Linha_Entry_1 = 'Salve a primeira entry nessa variavel'
Linha_Entry_2 = 'Salve a segunda entry nessa variavel'
Linha_Entry_3 = 'Salve a terceira entry nessa variavel'
#Resolvendo esse meu problema poderei terminar o programa
```

Answer (score 0):

`def` é função, e tudo o que você programa em uma função, só vale para ela. Portanto, arrumei seu código da seguinte forma, onde você pode ver o armazenamento dos dados das Entries mencionadas nas variáveis desejadas, através dos prints inseridos no código:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-

from Tkinter import *

janela = Tk()

def __init__():
    pass
def ok():
    nick = str(CaixaDeEntrada1.get())
    patente = str(CaixaDeEntrada2.get())
    pagpromocao = str(CaixaDeEntrada3.get())
    Linha_Entry_1 = nick
    Linha_Entry_2 = patente
    Linha_Entry_3 = pagpromocao
    print Linha_Entry_1
    print Linha_Entry_2
    print Linha_Entry_3
    CaixaDeEntrada3['bg'] = 'white'
    if nick in ' ':
        CaixaDeEntrada1['bg'] = 'pink'
        erro['text'] = 'Preencha todos os campos!'
    else:
        CaixaDeEntrada1['bg'] = 'white'
    if patente in ' ':
        CaixaDeEntrada2['bg'] = 'pink'
        erro['text'] = 'Preencha todos os campos!'
    else:
        CaixaDeEntrada2['bg'] = 'white'
    if pagpromocao in ' ':
        CaixaDeEntrada3['bg'] = 'pink'
        erro['text'] = 'Preencha todos os campos!'
    else:
        CaixaDeEntrada3['bg'] = 'white'
    if nick != '' and patente != '' and pagpromocao != '':
        janela.destroy()


#==========================================Janela Inicial:

titulo1 = Label(bg='#191970', font=('Arial', '14', 'bold'), fg='white', text='BEM VINDO ao RELATÓRIOS DIC')
titulo1.place(x='13', y='10')

CaixaDeEntrada1 = Entry(width=25, bg='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', '10'))
CaixaDeEntrada1.place(x=130, y=50)
Info1 = Label(font=('Arial', '11', 'bold'), fg='white', bg='#191970', text='Nick:')
Info1.place(x=10, y=50)

CaixaDeEntrada2 = Entry(width=25, bg='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', '10'))
CaixaDeEntrada2.place(x=130, y=75)
Info2 = Label(font=('Arial', '11', 'bold'), fg='white', bg='#191970', text='Patente:')
Info2.place(x=10, y=75)

CaixaDeEntrada3 = Entry(width=25, bg='white', font=('Comic Sans MS', '10'))
CaixaDeEntrada3.place(x=130, y=100)
Info3 = Label(font=('Arial', '11', 'bold'), fg='white', bg='#191970', text='Pág. Promoção:')
Info3.place(x=10, y=100)

erro = Label(bg='#191970', fg='red', font=('Arial', '11'), text='')
erro.place(x=135, y=125)

proximo = Button(width='39', text='Próximo', font=('Arial','10'), command=ok)
proximo.place(x=15, y=150)


#=======================================FimDaJanelaInicial

#Propriedades da janela:
janela.resizable(width=False, height=False)
janela.configure(bg='#191970')
#janela.wm_iconbitmap('ICO.ico')
janela.title('Relatórios DIC - Por WellersonOP')
janela.geometry('350x190+450+300')
janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, uma alternativa é usar uma variável global. Você pode capturar o dado da entrada e salvar em uma variável global, e depois usa-la em qualquer parte do código. Veja esse exemplo que eu fiz:

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except:
    from Tkinter import *

tela = Tk()

# Definição que vai "pegar" o texto da lbl e salvar em uma variável global
def salvar_dados():
   # Vamos criar uma variável global
   global armazenar_nome

   # Vamos dizer que ela recebe o texto do widget Entry
   armazenar_nome = nome_do_cliente.get()

# Texto Nome:
texto = Label(tela, text="Nome: ")
# Widget de Entrada
nome_do_cliente = Entry(tela)
# Botão de confirmação 
btn_enviar = Button(tela, text="Enviar",command=salvar_dados)

# Definindo a geometria de tela, eu não sei trabalhar bem com .pack()
texto.grid(row=1,column=1)
nome_do_cliente.grid(row=1,column=2)
btn_enviar.grid(row=2,column=1,columnspan=2)


'''A partir daqui só tem código referente a recuperação da variável com o nome do cliente'''


def recuperar():
    # Vamos tornar a variável disponível nessa definição
    global armazenar_nome

    # Vamos fazer o lbl_salvo receber o nome do cliente, armazenado na variável global
    lbl_salvo["text"] = armazenar_nome

# Label que vai receber o conteúdo da variável global
lbl_salvo = Label(tela, text="Aqui vai aparecer o nome do cliente")

# Botão que vai acionar o evento recuperar
btn_recuperar = Button(tela, text="Qual é o nome do cliente?",command=recuperar)

# Definindo a geometria de tela, eu não sei trabalhar bem com .pack()
lbl_salvo.grid(row=3,column=1,columnspan=2)
btn_recuperar.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

tela.mainloop()
```